# problems in sending email using sendgrid python django?

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am trying to send email using sendgrid using python django. For some reason, the email is being delivered but without the html content in it. What could I be doing wrong ?

```
def sendemail(sender,recipient,subject,content,url):
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey="")
    from_email = Email(sender)
    to_email = Email(recipient)
    subject = subject
    objects = {
        "message":content,
        "domain":url


    }

    html_content = get_template('sendemail.html').render(objects)
    print ('htmlcontent',html_content)


    content = Content("text/html",html_content)

    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set text/plain content as well.

You can try something like this :

```
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email)
mail.add_content(Content("text/plain", "plain message"))
mail.add_content(Content("text/html", html_content ))
```